# Range.getValue() of a 1-cell range takes 3 to 7 seconds to execute

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that used to run in well under a minute. Recently I started getting "Exceeded maximum execution time" errors indicating it now breaks the 6 minute limit.

Using 'Execution transcript' I found that the few getValue() and getValues() calls I make take very long time, so I experimented.

The following test function takes anywhere from 3 to 7 seconds to execute:

```
function test_singleCellRange_getValue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Marcin');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
  var value = range.getValue();
}
```

The 'Execution transcript' shows that the `getValue()` call takes all the time:

```
[17-10-29 14:15:00:002 EDT] Starting execution
[17-10-29 14:15:00:019 EDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
[17-10-29 14:15:00:074 EDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Marcin]) [0.054 seconds]
[17-10-29 14:15:00:075 EDT] Sheet.getRange([1, 1]) [0 seconds]
[17-10-29 14:15:07:377 EDT] Range.getValue() [7.301 seconds]
[17-10-29 14:15:07:381 EDT] Execution succeeded [7.36 seconds total runtime]
```

The single cell contains a constant string value (i.e. no formulas). Is this dismal performance of getValue() normal (i.e. the new performance standard to expect from Google's servers), or is there something I can do to improve performance?

### Update

Performance of `getValue()` appears to be heavily impacted by the size of the spreadsheet.  Even though the above code executes `getValue()` on a single cell range its performance appears to be impacted by the overall size of the spreadsheet.

This makes no sense - anyone has experience here?  Is this how Google designed the API or is this a bug?

Comment: You might like to take a look at [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

Comment: Thanks @Cooper.  I am aware of the best practices and I wrote my code accordingly.  It still does perform few getValues() calls on a single sheet so my only performance improvement option is to gobble up the entire sheet with a single getValues() call and than pick data within it - make code more difficult, but doable.  This would be a short term solution though - many sheets in the spreadsheet, and size constantly growing.

Comment: The "performance standard to expect from Google's servers", specifically for Apps Script, can only be expressed in terms such as "eventually" and "probably".

Comment: @Desire, you may be quite accurate :), regretably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using Sheets API v4? Please think of this as one of several answers. When I deal with large data in Spreadsheet, I often use Sheets API because of the process speed. I don't know whether this sample script is useful for your situation. If this is not useful for you, I'm sorry.

#### Sample script :

This sample script can retrieve the same result with your script.

```
var sheetId = "### Spreadsheet ID ###";
var range = "Sheet1!A1:A1";
var value = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sheetId, range);
// Logger.log(value.values)
```

In order to use this script, please enable Sheets API for Advanced Google Services and API console as follows.

#### Enable Sheets API v4 at Advanced Google Services

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Advanced Google Services
  - Turn on Google Sheets API v4

#### Enable Sheets API v4 at API console

- On script editor

  - Resources -> Cloud Platform project
  - View API console
  - At Getting started, click Enable APIs and get credentials like keys.
  - At left side, click Library.
  - At Search for APIs & services, input "sheets". And click Google Sheets API.
  - Click Enable button.

#### References :

- Advanced Google Services : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced
- Sheets API v4: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, this may be the best approach.  I am hoping to give it a try later this week.

Comment: @Marcin K I hope for achieving what you want to do.

Comment: @Marcin Was my answer useful for you?

Comment: I tried following your instructions to enable API v4 at API console.  I get as far as selecting "Getting started", but than I don't get an option to Enable APIs.  Instead Google is asking me to start a time-limited free trial.  Am I in the right place?

Comment: @Marcin K I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In order to understand your situation, can I see the screenshot?

Comment: @Marcin K How about accessing this URL. https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/sheets.googleapis.com At this URL, sheets api can be enabled. When you accessed the URL, you can see the project ID at URL as a query. Please check it whether that is the same to your project.

Comment: Thanks @Tanakey, I got it working.  Some interesting new findings.  The single cell getValue() using traditional API appears to have been significantly improved - first call on a sheet is on par with API v4, while subsequent calls on the same sheet, even different cells, are effectively 0 time - appears like a single getValue() results in fully cached sheet and subsequent calls are practically 0 cost.

Comment: ... while subsequent calls using API v4 all take the same longer time (approximately 1.2s in my tests). It seems that in this case traditional API using getValue() for single cell is faster.

Comment: ... measuring whole sheet performance I get similar call times for traditional API .getValues() and the equivalent API v4 calls.  It is possible that when I posted this question traditional API was much slower, but at this point in time it appears to be performing on par with API v4, better on multiple getValue() (i.e. single cell) calls.

Comment: @Marcin K Thank you for your additional information. But I'm sorry for not being helpful.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't anything that we can directly do to improve the performance of such script.

It's known that calling Google Apps Script services is slow.

For more complex scripts, take a look to the official guide posted on [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices).

Comment: Thanks @Rubén.  As I commented above, I am aware of the Best Practices and I code accordingly.  Being a service call, I would expect `.getValue()` to have a heavy per-call overhead, plus dependance on size of range being operated on.  It would also be reasonable to have the service re-calculate any formulas before returning values.  Performance depending on unrelated data in spreadsheet makes no sense and not workable long term.